# Create a specific SOAP action path. wash_out gem. Replace /action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, wsdl, wash-out

When I make `wash_out` routes with

```
wash_out :my_controller
```

it generates two path:

> http://myip/my_controller/wsdl  - default link to wsdl file
>
> http://myip/my_controller/action  - default link to action

I'd like to create specific links, because I make copy of existing service with ruby.
I can replace link to wsdl file with this:
get `'ua/wsdl/UnifiedApi.wsdl'`, to: `'ua#_generate_wsdl'`

But I haven't found any ways to replace action link.
I need it be such format:

> /my_controller/soap - link to action i need

Is any ideas how do it ?

Comment: I have such rake route, automaticly generated
my_controller_action_path GET|POST /my_controller/action #<WashOut::Router:0x007fd754b4a040 @controller_name="MyControllerController">
But i need /my_controller/soap

Comment: You could setup a redirect in your routes.rb  .